# How to Add a custom preview text with a message in python telegram bot

Tags: python, bots, telegram, telegram-bot

I tried this method to add a custom preview like the one that appears when you send a link in telegram but for a some reason it's not working.
How to fix this and the proper way to add custom preview

```
import telegram 

# create bot object
bot = telegram.Bot(token='YOUR_TOKEN') 

# set custom preview text
preview_text = 'This is a custom preview text' 

# send message with custom preview text
bot.send_message(chat_id='CHAT_ID', text='Your message here', 
                 parse_mode=telegram.ParseMode.HTML, 
                 disable_web_page_preview=False, 
                 reply_markup=None, 
                 disable_notification=False, 
                 timeout=None, 
                 reply_to_message_id=None,
                 allow_sending_without_reply=False,
                 **kwargs,
                 link_preview=True,
                 **kwargs).link_preview = preview_text
```

I tried this way but i got a error with using this method